Unable to log ship between to servers on different networks
I have two SQL DB VM's running in different tenants in Azure. We are migrating from one to the other and I am trying to setup log shipping between them. I have been following this doc:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2562/sql-server-log-shipping-to-a-different-domain-or-workgroup/

Both machines are running compatible versions of MSSQL.
Both machines have the same user added.
Both machines have their SQL server agent using the same user and pass.

I have teamed the two Virtual Networks together but at the moment I keep getting:

failed because Cannot open backup device '\Secondary server\LogShipping\databaseinquestion.trn'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).

the only difference I can think of between the machines is their PC name which when logging in makes the users different.

Is this error occurring when running the LSCopy or LSRestore job? Assuming LSRestore, it appears to be restoring from a share instead of a local folder. Have you set the permissions for the secondary service account on the share (not the folder permissions but the share permissions).

no this is at the first attempt to backup.

grant service running SQL on the source permissions to write to fileshare. test it by running manual backup to this fileshare
